# Low opacity Inbox

Tags: feature-request, design

The Inbox is semi-transparent:

[image: inbox]

Makes it visually gorgeous, however I find the color bands behind it seem to make arbitrary separations, which is a bit confusing. 
I don't have a screenshot right now, but new messages in the inbox, colored in bright orange with interspersed dark blue, lighter blue, etc, make this even worse.
Confusing-wise, not aesthetically (it was real pretty! :) )

Comment: See a long discussion of how this degree of transparency is not at all apparent to many users (depending e.g. on what angle they use when looking at their screen) at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1338826#1338826 - includes a more obvious version that has been color-curved via the gimp.

Comment: @AviD I don't have a strong preference on this one. I can either make the background solid, or darken the foreground text.

Comment: @Jin but most importantly, are *you* able to see this?? Anyway, is it possible to do a "masking" of the behind-colors? I think the transparency makes it look REALLY nice - but it just lines up confusingly... lacking any other solution, and considering that most other people dont even *see* that it's transparent, I would say just make it solid :(

Comment: @AviD - on my work laptop (HP Elitebook 2540p) I can see it :-) I don't think it matters either way, so happy for you to guide decision here if no-one objects.

Answer (score 1):

We're standardizing on a bit of transparency in the inbox across the network.